# How Show tablename with resultset in query?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a used query as follows:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ClaimsAdminName)) + ' | ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ClaimsAdminID)) AS Clientname
FROM tblClaimsAdmin
WHERE (ClaimsAdminName LIKE @Prefix)
UNION
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(EmployerFName + ' ' + EmployerLName)) + ' | ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(EmployerID)) AS Clientname
FROM tblEmployer
WHERE (EmployerFName LIKE @Prefix)
```

The result returned if I enter 's%' is :

s | 8
Sumit Singh | 16

Now is there any way so that i can return the tablename with the result set.Like from which table the value is coming.

I hope I am clear with my query.

Please help!

Thanks

Swaroop Kumar.P

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'table1' as tablename, otherfields
from table1
union all
select 'table2', otherfields
from table2
```